# How do I get the index of a sub-document retrieved from a query?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a code:

```
'items' => 

  array (

      0 => 
          array (   

              'name' => 'paste',

              'qty' => 5,

              'price' => 2.5,

          ),
      1 => 
          array (

              'name' => 'soap',

              'qty' => 5,

              'price' => 2.5,
          ),

      )
```

I am trying to write a query to find out the index of the value where the sub-document *items* has a data entry of *name* as "soap". Can anyone help me with the working solution?

Comment: thought of using multiple foreach loops ?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: There is no easy way to do this within MongoDB itself, you will need to filter this out client side in your PHP app

Comment: Yea I already thought of using multiple foreach loops but then that increases the complexity and I was wanting to know if there was a simple way of retrieving the index.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're after something along the lines of

```
foreach($items as $key => $value){
   if($value['name'] == "soap") $output = $key;
}
```

Where $output would be the key of the array with item set to soap